# Allow people to host their own multiplayer without port forwarding?

Tags: c++, port, multiplayer, steam

There's lots of games on Steam nowadays (Table Top Simulator, SpeedRunners) that allows people to host their own online multiplayer matches/games without the need for port forwarding.

One thing I thought of of how they do it is they simply have one server that processes all the matches as separate threads.

But then I'm starting to wonder about getting bottle necked.

I then heard these games simply somehow allow TCP to be holepunched through their NAT, getting past the need for port forwarding.

But how in say, C++ using winsock, would one do this? Or GameMaker: Studio? Or just any game in general? How do you allow people to play without port forwarding? What's the process?

I see so many games on Steam do it nowadays it must not be too complicated.

Comment: *"I see so many games on Steam do it nowadays it must not be too complicated."* How does one imply the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One may use UPnP to automatically configure the router to do the port forwarding. There's a library for that in http://pupnp.sourceforge.net/

The alternative way is to have a external server managing all traffic, so that everyone connects there, thus avoiding nat issues.

Comment: Do games actually automatically configure port forwarding on routers? Does anyone know of any games that do this because that's actually really interesting.

Also for your second option, wouldn't the external server have a lot of bandwidth having to host tons of matches all in one server?

Comment: Also when a game configures port forwarding on your router, does it stay permamently? Or is it temporary while the game is running?

Comment: "Do games actually automatically configure port forwarding on routers?" - Yes, mostly when you host a game. Skype, some torrent clients are also examples of applications using this tech.

Comment: "Also for your second option, wouldn't the external server have a lot of bandwidth having to host tons of matches all in one server?" - Yes.

Comment: "Also when a game configures port forwarding on your router, does it stay permamently?" - It's a temporary thing

Answer (score 3):

As this question is explicitely related to steam, I think it's worth mentioning the steamworks API, especially SteamNetworking. It allows peer-to-peer connection relaying through steam servers:

https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/api/ISteamNetworking

```
bool AllowP2PPacketRelay( bool bAllow );
```

> Allow or disallow P2P connections to fall back to being relayed
>   through the Steam servers if a direct connection or NAT-traversal
>   cannot be established.

Comment: Very useful if you already plan on using Steam by itself, but probably not going to happen on Mobile